# How do I get java to open cmd and combine a folder of csv files?

Tags: java

I am trying to get a java based macro I use to combine all of the .csv files it spits out into one, and the only way I know how to do that is to open up cmd and manually paste in the folder directory. I know almost nothing about java and pretty little about programming in general, and the person who make the macro i use is in a different country rn so i cant ask him for help.

It takes forever to paste all of the results into one csv, and while using cmd is easier it would be nice if I could just have the macro do it for me. That said, I wanted to ask if it is at all possible to even do that?

Any help would be appreciated! If possible, I would also like to get the macro to automatically combine the headings for the csv files.

Also also, the macro has a dialogue box come up that then leads to you selecting the file directory. is it possible to have the cmd command reference the directory already defined by the macro?

java based macro meaning like 20 lines of text written in java... idk i'm a biochemist not a programer. I'm doin my best.

Comment: all the csv files share the same structure? (matching headers?)

Comment: There is no such thing as a `Java based macro', and your question is too broad by far.

Comment: Are the files have the same headers? If so, merging all of them is a peace of cake.

Comment: yeah all the files have identical headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Path> paths = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("csv1.csv"), Paths.get("csv2.csv"));
        List<String> mergedLines = getMergedLines(paths);
        Path target = Paths.get("mergecsv.csv");
        Files.write(target, mergedLines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    private static List<String> getMergedLines(List<Path> paths) throws IOException {
        List<String> mergedLines = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (Path p : paths){
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
                if (mergedLines.isEmpty()) {
                    mergedLines.add(lines.get(0)); //add header only once
                }
                mergedLines.addAll(lines.subList(1, lines.size()));
            }
        }
        return mergedLines;
    }
}
```

## File1

```
header1,header2,header3
one,two,three
four,five,six
```

## File2

```
header1,header2,header3
seven,eight,nine
ten,eleven,twelve
```

## Result

```
header1,header2,header3
one,two,three
four,five,six
seven,eight,nine
ten,eleven,twelve
```

## To compile the program

```
javac CSV.java
```

## To run the program

```
java CSV
```